# Django session authentication and disabled cookies

Tags: django, cookies, django-authentication, sessionid

Does session authentication in django have anaything to do with cookies?Would it work if a user has cookies disabled on his browser? Should django warn users if their browsers have cookies disabled?

Comment: RTFD https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/ :D

Answer (score 4):

No, authentication is cookie-based - **session ID** stored in cookies!

> The Django sessions framework is entirely, and solely, cookie-based.
>   It does not fall back to putting session IDs in URLs as a last resort,
>   as PHP does. This is an intentional design decision. Not only does
>   that behavior make URLs ugly, it makes your site vulnerable to
>   session-ID theft via the “Referer” header.

There is workarounds, for example you can put the session ID in the query string. Check this article: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/cookieless-django-sessions-and-authentication-with

Warning from author: **don't do what I'm about to describe unless you understand the potential security consequences**

Middleware that get session id from `request.GET` and put it in `request.COOKIES` (FakeSessionCookie middleware has to be placed before the SessionMiddleware in settings.py):

```
from django.conf import settings

class FakeSessionCookieMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.COOKIES.has_key(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME) \
            and request.GET.has_key(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME):
            request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = \
                request.GET[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
```

After authentication you should include session id as url (GET) parameter in all requests to server.

Comment: Link is broken. Archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20100310200428/http://www.stereoplex.com/2007/nov/7/cookieless-django-sessions-and-authentication-with/

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:

> Django provides full support for anonymous sessions. The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID – not the data itself...
>   [more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

django uses cookie based sessions, so without cookies authentication won't work.